# Server down after updating SSL certificates

Tags: ssl-certificate, ssl-certificate-errors

I'm by no means an expert in this area, so I apologize if the question is dumb. I'm updating the SSL certificates on a client's website, but after updating the conf file the server went down. Apache could not start. I could only resolve the issue by reverting the changes to the conf file.

Here is what I had written in the conf file (site name obscured for privacy):

```
# SSLCertificateFile      /etc/ssl/certs/XXXX_XXXX_exp-6-29-25.csr
# SSLCertificateKeyFile /etc/ssl/private/XXXX_exp-6-29-25.key
# SSLCertificateChainFile /etc/ssl/certs/XXX.XXXX.org.pem
```

The error.log had a few of these:

```
[Fri Jun 10 15:49:29.281400 2022] [ssl:emerg] [pid 5958] AH02561: Failed to configure certificate XXXX.XXXX.org:443:0, check /etc/ssl/certs/XXXX_XXXX_exp-6-29-25.csr
[Fri Jun 10 15:49:29.281458 2022] [ssl:emerg] [pid 5958] SSL Library Error: error:0909006C:PEM routines:get_name:no start line (Expecting: CERTIFICATE) -- Bad file contents or format - or even just a forgotten SSLCertificateKeyFile?
[Fri Jun 10 15:49:29.281470 2022] [ssl:emerg] [pid 5958] SSL Library Error: error:140AD009:SSL routines:SSL_CTX_use_certificate_file:PEM lib
```

Am I using the wrong file types? Obviously I can't post the actual certificates, but if you have any ideas, let me know what to check for.

Thank you!

Ubuntu version 18.04

Apache2 version 2.4.29

Comment: it looks for me that you did not specified the correct file, it tells that the file is not valid due missing certificate header. please verify. And csr stands mostly for Certification Signing Request, its mostly the file that is needed to issue a certificate

Comment: yes @djdomi that is what it's saying. I can only work with what I have (a csr, key, and pem) - but maybe I'm missing a step?

Comment: Do you have `#` in front of the lines in your config?

Comment: try `grep -i certificate /etc/ssl/certs/XXXX_XXXX_exp-6-29-25.csr`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you only have a *Certificate Signing Request* (`.csr`) then you do not have a certificate. You have to send the CSR to a *Certification Authority* (CA) for signing and use the certificate (`.crt`, `.cer` or sometimes `.pem`) you get as a response with your [`SSLCertificateFile` directive](https://httpd.apache.org/docs/current/mod/mod_ssl.html#sslcertificatefile). This is the correct workflow for both internal and public CAs, although the exact procedure for validation varies a lot.

You can distinguish between a CSR and a certificate by examining the first line of the PEM encoded file:

- A *Certificate Signing Request* starts with:

  - `-----BEGIN CERTIFICATE SIGNING REQUEST-----` or
  - `-----BEGIN CERTIFICATE REQUEST-----`
- A certificate starts with `-----BEGIN CERTIFICATE-----`.

Comment: This is extremely helpful. I sent the csr through a 3rd party (who isn't very responsive), and received only pem file. The pem file does start with

-----BEGIN CERTIFICATE-----

Is that the file I should be applying to SSLCertificateFile?

Comment: Exactly! The link on my answer tells it: the `SSLCertificateFile` accepts "Server PEM-encoded X.509 certificate data file or token identifier".